# How to get one product by id in params using mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I am trying to get one product by id from the params from mongodb. Currently I can fetch all products but I have no idea how to get the details of one product when I click on it. Can anybody help?

API.js

```
router.route('/products/:_id').get(function (req, res) {
  db.collection('products').findOne({"_id":ObjectId(req.params._id)},(err,results)=>{
    res.send(results);
  })
  })

router.route('/products').get(function (req, res) {
  db.collection('products').find().toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

Product service.ts
(My failed attempt)

```
 getOneProduct(){
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url);
  }
```

Pictures of problems
[Can get all products in the homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c0rN.png)
[Can get Id in params but dont know how to fetch details of 1 product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAqcs.png)

**Updated api.js**

```
router.route('/products').get(function (req, res) {
  db.collection('products').find().toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});

router.route('/products/:_id').get(function (req, res) {
  db.collection('products').findOne({"_id":ObjectId(req.params._id)},(err,results)=>{
    res.send(results);
  })
  })
```

**Updated product-component.ts**

```
 getOneProduct(_id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.url}/${_id}`);
  }
```

**Updated product-component.ts** (I do not know how to call the function here)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CartService } from '../cart.service';
import { FavService } from '../fav.service';
import { products } from '../models/products';
import { ProductsService } from '../products.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
 
  
  // products!: products;
  productsList:any=[];
  id: string = '';
  private sub: any;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private productService: ProductsService,
    private cartService:CartService, private router:Router, private favService: FavService) { 
    
    
 
  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    
     
  }

activeTab:string = 'Delivery';
onTabClick(tab: string){
  this.activeTab = tab;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you receive the response from API? Can you share the response as JSON? While I believe that you need to pass the selected product Id through URL to the API, which your current code `getOneProduct` method didn't apply it.

Comment: what do you mean by response from API :")

Comment: Mean that when you submit the HTTP request (from the front-end) to API, your API will process the request and return the value result back. The value result is the [response](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.2?topic=protocol-http-responses).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass the product id of the single product.
Ps.: Please use a type for the products.

```
getAllProducts(): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.url);
  }

getOneProduct(id: number): Observable<Product> {
    return this.http.get<Product>(`${this.url}/${id}`);
  }
```

Comment: Im trying to follow your solution but I am not sure how to call it in the product-details.component.ts. (which is the page I am calling the product details)

Comment: That is some part of the code you didn't provide. Please add those details to your question

Comment: Hi I have updated the code above, I am not sure how and where to call get one product in the product.component.ts